# Application.OnKey error with "%a" keystroke

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in the 'ThisWorkbook' object:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "^a", "SS_1"
    Application.OnKey "^%a", "SS_1"
    Application.OnKey "%a", "SS_1"
End Sub
```

In a seperate module, I have the following code:

```
Sub SS_1()
MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

Both the `"^a"` and the `"^%a"` keystrokes execute the `SS_1` sub perfectly, and the MsgBox appears.

However, the `"%a"` keystroke appears to do nothing, and no message box gets displayed.

Are there any unique factors that I am unaware of that would cause this keystroke to operate differently than the other keystrokes?

Thank you in advance for your help,

Scott

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+a` does not work for me. Are you sure it works for you?

Comment: I have not tried `Ctrl+Shift+a`.  I have only tried `Ctrl+a`, `Ctrl+Alt+a` and `Alt+a`.

Comment: What's point here assigning multiple shortcuts to the same macro?

Comment: I only want `Alt+a`.  The others were just a test to see if other keystroke combinations were working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Application.OnKey "^a", "Macro1"
    Application.OnKey "^%a", "Macro2"
    Application.OnKey "%a", "Macro3"

    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",false)"

End Sub

Public Sub Macro1()

    Debug.Print "Pryc"

End Sub

Public Sub Macro2()

    Debug.Print "Pryc2"

End Sub

Public Sub Macro3()

    Debug.Print "Pryc3"

End Sub

Public Sub UnTestMe() 'Run this to disable the shortcuts.

    Application.OnKey "^a"
    Application.OnKey "^%a"
    Application.OnKey "%a"

    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",true)"

End Sub
```

Edit:
To make sure works, you should hide the ribbon. Otherwise, it finds something on the ribbon, which is with `A` and uses it as a screenshot.

Try this to hide the ribbon:
`Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",false)"`

Try this to return it:
`Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",true)"`

Comment: Tried this code as well, but with the same results - `%a` does not appear to be assigning the key stroke.  I tried your code for all 26 letters of the alphabet, and only the following letters worked: "b", "c", "g", "j", "k", "q", "s", "u", "y", and "z".  Some of the other key combinations appeared to behave as normal (such as `%h`, when pressed, would activate the "Home" tab in the ribbon).  Are there any other background processes in Excel that would override my macros and prevent me from being able to use the other 16 letters of the alphabet?

Comment: I found why I was able to do it - see the edit. And usually, many keys on the keyboard are used from Excel. If I have to use a shortcut, I use `Ctrl+e`, as far as it is somehow not taken. But you probably have a good reason to do use `Alt+a`, I suppose.

Comment: With this edit, the hotkey now works like a charm.  I should be able to make this work for my own purposes in the short term.  However, in the long term, do you foresee any solution that does not involve hiding the ribbon?  If at some point in the future, I wanted to share this macro, i would not want to have to require the user(s) to hide their ribbon.

Comment: Theoretically if there is a solution, not involving hiding the ribbon, it would be probably too difficult and would involive registry changes. That's too much of a price for a shortcut, I think.